# Is it better to perform n additions of a floating-point number or one integer multiplication?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

Consider the two cases below:

```
// Case 1
double val { initial_value };
for (int i { 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
    val += step;
    foo(val);
}
```

```
// Case 2
for (int i { 0 }; i < n; ++i) {
    double val = initial_value + i * step;
    foo(val);
}
```

where `n` is the number of steps, `initial_value` is some given value of type `double`, `step` is some predetermined value of type `double` and `val` is a variable used in subsequent call for the function `foo`. Which of the cases produces less of floating-point error? My guess would be the second one, as there are only one addition and multiplication, while the first case incurs the floating-point representation error from all of the `n` additions. I am asking this question because I didn't know *what* to search for. Does there exists some good reference for cases like these?

In practice the variable `val` is to be used in the loop of the both cases. I didn't include any example for this as I'm only interested in the floating-point error.

Comment: Generally, the more operations you do, the chance for rounding errors changing the results increases. That said, depending on the actual values, it might make no difference.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux See the edit.

Comment: In practice, it's hard to say which is technically better. Intuitively I would prefer the second version due to each value being calculated using fewer operations, but I can't provide any evidence for that. Putting the technical side aside, I would favor the second example simply because it seems easier to understand the intent of the code, and you can make `val` a `const` which further facilitates understanding the function's logic (assuming the actual loop is or could become more cluttered).

Comment: In daily business, I usually prefer the Case 2, as the Case 1 is more prone to "drifting away" due to accumulated errors.

Comment: Both are flawed. You should compute the start and end, then compute each value as a function of those. The problem with the second way is you multiply the error in step. The former accumulates errors. Note the two snippets are not equivalent due to the increment happening early in the first snippet.

Comment: _I didn't know what to search for._ Maybe, "error accumulation" or ["error propagation"](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/) (combined with "floating point" in case).

Comment: @Bathsheba What if the end is not known beforehand (like in OPs case) but subject of unpredictable events (like e.g. user interaction)? ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Isn't the end equal to `initial_value + step * n` in both OP's examples?

Comment: @Bob__ Bad wording. :-( Yes, in OPs case, it's known but what if not...

Comment: Please note that since C++20 you can use [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat If not, well, I'd also prefer the second snippet.

Comment: @Bob__: The point is that in many scenarios one might want a sequence of values that are uniformly spaced between *specified* start and end points.  Using the second approach would yield values that are as uniformly spaced as possible between the start point and an end value that's near a desired one, but may not quite match.

Comment: The best result is obtained by `std::fma(i, step, initial_value)`. This will produce the `double` value nearest the real-arithmetic result of `i`•`step`+`initial_value`, presuming that `step` and `initial_value` are `double` and `i` is a `double` value (is not so large it is changed by rounding when converted to `double`). `fma` has no internal rounding error. That is, the result of the multiplication is not rounded before the addition; the result is as if the multiplication and addition were performed with no rounding prior to the final result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758451/is-it-better-to-perform-n-additions-of-a-floating-point-number-of-one-integer-mu#comment123307270_69758451) by [supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363751) (emphasis mine):

> The point is that in many scenarios one might want a sequence of values that are uniformly spaced between specified start and end points. Using the second approach would yield **values that are as uniformly spaced as possible** between the start point and an end value that's near a desired one, but may not quite match.

And the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758451/is-it-better-to-perform-n-additions-of-a-floating-point-number-of-one-integer-mu#comment123306900_69758451) by [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830):

> Both are flawed. You should compute the start and end, then compute each value as a function of those. The problem with the second way is you multiply the error in step. The former accumulates errors.

I'd suggest a couple of alternatives.

- Since C++20, the Standard Library provides [std::lerp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) where `std::lerp(a, b, t)` returns "the linear interpolation between a and b for the parameter t (or extrapolation, when t is outside the range [0,1])".
- A formula like `value = (a * (n - i) + b * i) / n;` may result in a more uniform<sup>1</sup> distribution of the intermediate values.

(1) [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/67b3hP344) I tried to test all those approaches for different extremes and number of sample points. The program compares the values generated by each algorithm when applied in the opposite directions (first from left to right, then from right to left). It shows the average and variance of the sum of the absolute difference between the values of the intermediate points.

Other metrics may yield different results.

Answer (score 4):

Including `<cmath>` and using `std::fma(i, step, initial_value)` will always produce the best result, presuming `i` is not so large that converting it to the floating-point type has a rounding error. This is because `fma` is specified to produce a result equivalent to computing the real-arithmetic value of `i`•`step` + `initial_value` and then rounding it to the nearest representable value. It does not have an internal rounding after the multiplication and before the addition, so it produces the best result that is representable in the floating-point type.

Between the multiplication method and the addition method, multiplication is generally preferred. It is possible for addition to produce a better result. Presuming IEEE-754 double precision binary, an example is easily constructed as `initial_value = -1./3`, `i = 3`, and `step = 1./3`. Then in `initial_value + step + step + step`, `initial_value + step` produces exactly zero (so there is no rounding error), adding `step` has no error, and the second add merely doubles `step`, which also has no error. So addition produces a final result with no error. In contrast, in `initial_value + 3*step`, `3*step` has a rounding error, and it persists through the addition.

However, outside of deliberately constructed examples, multiplication will commonly produce better results than addition, simply because it uses fewer operations, many fewer in most cases. Typically, the rounding errors in repeated additions will act like a random walk, sometimes increasing the accumulated error and sometimes decreasing it. A random walk can sometimes return to the origin but does so rarely. So it is rare that a sequence with many additions will have accumulated error closer to the origin (zero error) than an expression with one multiplication and one addition.

Comment: "Repeated additions act like a random walk, sometimes increasing the accumulated error and sometimes decreasing it." This is such a choice quote from this answer, and very valuable. Thanks for so succinctly elaborating the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 has significantly lower error.

How much? Well, let's assume an `initial_value` of `0` for simplicity sake at first. You have 53 significant bits, and how quickly you will see rounding errors depends how quickly we can manage to shift these off the far end during addition.

So let's pick `step` such that the significant bits are ideally all 1s: `0.999999999999999999999999`.

Now the rounding error is `log2(val/step)` bits from the far end of `step` during each single addition. Not much during the first iteration, but the error becomes noticable rather quickly.

Picking a huge `initial_value` and the error can become quite extreme. For `initial_value >= pow(2, 53) * step`, your first loop even fails to change `val` at all in between iterations.

Your second loop still handles that correctly.

Comment: @alias the result is only better by 1 bit, and that's already the upper bound for the error in multiplication. The upper bound for addition computes as above, and can be constructed to be arbitrarily bad with any sufficient number of additions.

Comment: @Ext3h: alias’s addition result is not better at all; the addition and multiplication results are equally far away from the real-arithmetic result, and the rule for ties is to round to even, which the multiplication result produces and the addition result does not. The addition result only “looked” better when the values were converted to numerals with limited digits, which introduced further rounding errors that gave a false appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an extreme case. Suppose that `initial_value` is much larger than `step`. Much, much larger. So large that `initial_value + step == initial_value` due to the limits of floating point representation. However, we do not want this "extreme" case to get too extreme. Put a cap on `initial_value`, say keep it small enough to have `initial_value + (2*step) != initial_value`. (Some people might call this putting `step` between a certain epsilon and half that epsilon, but I would get the terminology mixed up.) Now run through your code.

In the first loop, `val` will equal `initial_value` every iteration as no operation is performed that will change its value. In contrast, the second loop will eventually have a different value for `val`, if there are enough iterations. Therefore, the second option, the one that calculates `initial_value + i * step` is more accurate in this extreme case.

---

We should also look at the opposite extremity. Suppose that `initial_value` is so small relative to `step` that `initial_value + step == step`. In this case, `initial_value` might as well be zero, and the question simplifies to asking if there is a more accurate way to calculate `i*step` than by multiplying `i` and `step`. (If there is, I might want a new compiler.) Therefore, the second option is not worse than the first in this extreme case.

---

Extreme case analysis is not conclusive, but it often reveals trends. I pushed the calculation to opposite extremes, and the second option varied from definitely better to definitely not worse. I'd be willing to conclude that the second option produces less error.

*Caveats:* It might be that the size of the error is negligible and not worth coding around. Also, the question has limited scope, ignoring other considerations (such as from where `step` came; if it is the result of dividing by `n`, there might be even better alternatives). Still, in the narrow scenario presented by the question, calculating `initial_value + i*step` each iteration looks like the way to get minimal numerical error.